# DELETE OR BLOCK INSERT FUNCTION FOR TIMELY MANNER

Tags: sql

Is there any way that I can delete inserting entry or block inserting entry into tables. I just want to avoid duplicate entries into system by mistakes.
For instance

```
**Date_Timing**                **team**         **score**
2016-10-16-10:32:08            baseball            11
2016-10-16-10:32:11            basketball           8
2016-10-16-10:32:12            Soccer              12  
2016-10-16-10:32:14            Soccer              12
2016-10-16-10:32:15            baseball            10
2016-10-16-10:32:16            baseball            10
```

I would like to avoid duplicate entries indicated above. delete automatically any duplicated entries in every 2 seconds should be okay.  I have used

```
delete
    from Sport
    where date_timing >= dateadd(MINUTE, 1,getdate());
```

But did not worked out for me!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do us a favor and rip your capslock keep off your keyboard, take it out back, and set it on fire.

Comment: But first, turn off caplocks.

Comment: What do you consider "duplicate entries" ?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: It seems very dangerous to automatically delete data on a schedule. A better solution would be to prevent whatever is inserting the duplicate data in the first place, either by adding constraints, cleaning data at the source, checking for existing records before inserting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [unique constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) so only 1 row with the same data can exist in the table. This way if you insert a new row with the same combination of **team** and **score** the database will throw an exception.

```
create table sport
(
  date_timing   timestamp,
  team          text,
  score         int,

  unique (team, score)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger that gets executed every time an insert action happens.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgValidateInput 
ON Sport 
FOR INSERT
AS
DELETE
FROM Sport
WHERE date_timing >= dateadd(MINUTE, 1,getdate());
```

Whats is exactly the dbms you're using so I can provide the proper syxtax?
This example is for MS-SQL Server